# Getting monthly scores in total score query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with quiz answers. The following query sums up the total for each participant in a given game.

```
SELECT @prev := @curr,
@curr := totalscore,
@rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank + @i) AS rank,
IF(@prev <> totalscore, @i:=1, @i:=@i+1) AS counter,
user_id, name, totalscore

FROM

(
SELECT scoringtable.user_id, scoringtable.name, sum(scoringtable.score) AS totalscore

FROM
scoringtable
WHERE game='B'
GROUP BY scoringtable.user_id ORDER BY totalscore DESC
)as scoringtable,(SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 1, @i := 0) tmp_tbl
```

See working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd097/2

However, In the table where I show the totals I also want to show the points gained every month by creating a column for each month. I understand that I can get the data with a query like this:

```
SELECT score AS 'january' FROM `scoringtable` WHERE month=1
```

but how can I incorporate something similar in the existing query for all 12 months?

Comment: In general, issues of data display are best handled in the presentation layer (e.g., with a bit of PHP)

Comment: ...and your schema is in need of normalisation

Answer (score 0):

You may use case as in the below lines:
SELECT (case when month =1 then score end)
 AS 'january' 
 (case when month = 2 then score end)
 AS 'Feb'
FROM `scoringtable`

Comment: I think this what I after. I can now display the January and February columns, but the information in the January column is not correct, and the Febraury column displays NULL. Here's what I did: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63c3f/2